# Summoning stored images

Tags: iphone, image, call, hidden

I have images in my iphone application I would like to summon when needed.

The idea is when the user takes a photo and it's loaded on the imageview, he or she will be able to call out my custom images that's preloaded in the app. The user can then move the custom image around their original photo.

My question is, how do I implement that? How do I store custom image for the user to call out later on?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry. My question is, how do I implement that? How do I store custom image for the user to call out later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have image files imported into your project and you'd like to show them on-screen?

Say you want to display the image "paintcan.jpg".  All you have to do is create an image view, set its image, and add it to the main view.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)] autorelease];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paintcan"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: That is correct. For example I have 5 images. I would like to hide them. So they don't show right away. Is there a way the user can somehow call or summon one of the images (when needed) to the view? I was thinking putting a little button on the screen for the user to press and see what images he can summon.

Comment: That sounds like the right way to do it... just put this code in an IBAction method and connect that to your button.  If you want more images, use more IBActions.

Comment: ONe more thing... I'm trying to figure out how to drag and possibly resize this image using touches. But mainly dragging for now. Right now when the user taps on the button itll show the image. But the image is fixed and cannot move. Is there a way to make it draggable?